# Can someone help? Im trying to create then modify a table. INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_Sex"

Tags: sql, insert, check-constraints

```
I am attempting to create a table then add and modify it. Below is how I created the table. The other part is the first record I attempted to add to the the table that has given me the check constrain Error
```

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_Sex". The conflict occurred in database "MHaynes_F22", table "dbo.DogLicense", column 'Sex'.
The statement has been terminated.

CREATE TABLE DogLicense

(

License int identity (1,1) primary key Not Null,
Expires date,
Sex nvarchar(15),
PetName nvarchar(20),
Breed nvarchar(20),
OwnerLastName nvarchar(30),
OwnerFirstName nvarchar(30),
Address nvarchar(50),
Zip nvarchar(5),
Phone nvarchar(10),

CONSTRAINT chk_Sex CHECK (Sex IN ('M(Male)', 'F(Female)','NM(Neutered Male)','SF(Spayed Female)')),
CONSTRAINT chk_Expires CHECK(Expires > '01/01/1990'))

this is the first records I attempted to insert

insert  DogLicense values('06/21/2023','NM','Rosco','St.Bernard','Freeman','Mark','123 Meadow Ln.','99207','(509) 555-1212')

Comment: you have to enter 'NM(Neutered Male)' but you are entering 'NM'

Comment: Thank you that worked !! I was thinking  the instructions were to include both.

Comment: 'Instructions'? do you mean 'allow both variations'? if so, it will make it very difficult to search/report on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check constraints are strict. Because you asked it to accept only  'NM(Neutered Male)' (and others but not 'NM') you can only use that value:

```
insert DogLicense 
values('06/21/2023','NM(Neutered Male)','Rosco','St.Bernard','Freeman','Mark','123 Meadow Ln.','99207','(509) 555-1212')
```